# Question regarding Legendre symbol and Quadratic reciprocity.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How would determine the value of the following Legendre symbol is $1$ or $-1$?
$$\left(\frac{\frac{p - 1}{2}}{p}\right)$$

So far, I've been able to figure out this much:

$$\left(\frac{p - 1}{p}\right) = \left(\frac 2p\right)\left(\frac{\frac{p - 1}{2}}{p}\right)$$

I know that $\left(\frac 2p\right) = \pm 1$, but how can I use this fact in order to move forward?

Comment: $p-1\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, and there's a formula for that Legendre symbol.

Comment: $(p-1|p) = (-1|p).$ So you need to know your prime $p \pmod 8.$

Comment: Both formulas you need can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.E2.88.921_and_the_first_supplement).  Cute problem.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize, we have the formulae: $$(\dfrac{2}{p})=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$$
$$(\dfrac{-1}{p})=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}.$$
Thus, $$(\dfrac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{p})=(\dfrac{-1}{p})(\dfrac{2}{p})=(-1)^{((p+2)^2-9)/8}.$$
Inform me of any point that needs to be improved, or that is not suited here.
Thanks in advance.